# How to solve equation ${z^3 = i}$ in the complex plane using polar form?

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm just wondering how can I solve equation

$${z^3 = i}$$

in polar form of complex numbers?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried this: $z^3 = r^3 \cdot (\cos(3\phi) + i \cdot \sin(3\phi)$ and $i = \cos(\frac{\pi}{2}) + i \cdot \sin(\frac{\pi}{2})$.

Comment: That's a good start. Now take those two equations, set their right hand sides equal to each other to make a new equation, and ask yourself: What values of $r>0$ and $\phi \in \mathbb R$ make the two sides of the new equation equal?

Comment: So, I get: $3\phi = k \cdot \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $r^3 = 1$, so I get $r = 1$ and $\phi = k \cdot \frac{\pi}{6}$. Then I got the angles of $0, \frac{\pi}{6}, \frac{\pi}{3}$.

Comment: Is that right??

Comment: The equation $3\phi=k\cdot \frac{\pi}{2}$ is incorrect, since the angle $1\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{\pi}{2}$ is not equal to $2\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}=\pi$. However, $\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi$. Hope that helps.

Comment: @GarethMa well, ${\frac{\pi}{2} \neq \frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi}$ xD but if you take the ${\cos}$ of both sides or the ${\sin}$ of both sides of that statement then they become equal

Comment: Oh I meant like as an angle

Comment: @GarethMa indeed yeah, so ${\frac{\pi}{2} = \frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi \mod(2\pi)}$ (or since the period of both ${\sin}$ and ${\cos}$ is ${2\pi}$ - this means taking the cosine of both sides will be equal or taking the sine of both sides will be equal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it in the comment section; the mistake was

$${3\phi = k\cdot \frac{\pi}{2}}$$

Instead, it should be

$${3\phi = \frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi k, k = \{0,1,2\}}$$

Since ${\sin(x)}$ and ${\cos(x)}$ both have period ${2\pi}$. This will mean that

$${\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi k\right), k \in \mathbb{Z}}$$

and

$${\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi k\right), k \in \mathbb{Z}}$$

This gives you

$${\phi = \frac{\pi}{6} + \frac{2\pi k}{3}, k=\{0,1,2\}}$$

Can you take it from here?